# MongoDB - Index not used when using a $ne and a $in with a compount multikey index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

```
        db.test.find().pretty();
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5537f2cfba0bf10870747d7e"),
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : [
            "abcd",
            "xyz"
        ]
    }


    db.test.getIndexes();
    [
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "a" : 1,
                "b" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "name" : "a_1_b_1"
        }
    ]

db.test.find({a: { $ne : 2}, b : { $in : ["abcd", "xyz"]}}).explain();
{
    **"cursor" : "BasicCursor", - doesn't hits index**.
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "vishals-Mac-mini.local:27017"
}
```

Other queries,

```
db.test.find({a: 1, b : { $in : ["abcd", "xyza"]}}) 
db.test.find({a: { $ne : 2}, b : { $in : ["abcd", "xyza"]}})
```

use the index.
Hitting the index seem to be dependent on the values specified in the $in array. If it contains all the values of an existing document then the index is not used.

Mongo version - 2.4.6

thanks.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? 2.6 uses the index as expected for every query you posted.

Answer (score 4):

In the **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why)**, it states that:

> The **`$ne`** and **`$nin`** operators are not selective. [See Create
> Queries that Ensure Selectivity](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/#index-selectivity). If you need to use these, it is
> often best to make sure that an additional, more selective criterion
> is part of the query.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understand that $ne is not selective and I would have expected it to do a complete index scan but at the very least it should have alteast hit the index and not resort to basic cursor. More so, whats confusing is that $ne does hit the index for certain queries based on the values in the $in clause.